# Best way to store timestamp with milliseconds in a mysql database

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

The value I want to insert into a mysql table has the following format: `YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS.MS` (MS is for milliseconds). E.g.: `2017-09-07 00:00:31.150`

[Official mysql docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html) for the DATE, DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP types say nothing about milliseconds so that's why I am asking.

*Please, tell me what mysql data type best fits for storing timestamps like mine?*

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Offisional documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fractional-seconds.html